# How to match a column entry in pandas against another similar column entry in a different row?

Tags: python, pandas

Say for a given table :

```
d.DataFrame([['Johnny Depp', 'Keanu Reeves'],
             ['Robert De Niro', 'Nicolas Cage'],
             ['Brad Pitt', 'Johnny Depp'],
             ['Leonardo DiCaprio', 'Morgan Freeman'],
             ['Tom Cruise', 'Hugh Jackman'],
             ['Morgan Freeman', 'Robert De Niro']],
             columns=['Name1', 'Name2'])
```

I wish the output as :

```
pd.DataFrame([['Johnny Depp', 'Johnny Depp'],
              ['Robert De Niro', 'Robert De Niro'],
              ['Brad Pitt', NaN],
              ['Leonardo DiCaprio', NaN],
              ['Tom Cruise', NaN],
              ['Morgan Freeman', 'Morgan Freeman'],
              [NaN ,'Keanu Reeves'],
              [NaN ,'Nicolas Cage'],
              [NaN ,'Hugh Jackman']],
              columns=['Name1', 'Name2'])
```

I wish to map similar names in the two columns against each other, and the rest as seperate row entries.
I know Regex can solve this, but I want this at scale since I have a lot of rows. I tried using different inbuilt pandas functions and word libraries like FastText but couldn't solve this.

I wish to map column Name1 to Name2.

How do i solve this ? PS. I still think am making some silly errors.

Comment: Whta is the logic behind the output?

Comment: I wish to map similar names in the two columns against each other,  and the rest as seperate row entries.

Answer (score 0):

First, you make a list with all the actors' names.

```
actors = ['Johnny Depp', 'Keanu Reeves',
      'Robert De Niro', 'Nicolas Cage',
      'Brad Pitt', 'Johnny Depp',
      'Leonardo DiCaprio', 'Morgan Freeman',
      'Tom Cruise', 'Hugh Jackman',
      'Morgan Freeman', 'Robert De Niro',
]
```

Then use the collections.Counter class. It is a powerful class which is used when we
want to find the frequency of an element.

```
from collections import Counter

actors_counts = Counter(actors)
actors_list = list(actors_counts.items())
print(actors_list)
```

Then we make a pandas DataFrame,

```
import pandas as pd
actors_df = pd.DataFrame(actors_list, columns=['Name','Frequency'])
print(actors_df)
```

It outputs,

```
                Name  Frequency
0        Johnny Depp          2
1       Keanu Reeves          1
2     Robert De Niro          2
3       Nicolas Cage          1
4          Brad Pitt          1
5  Leonardo DiCaprio          1
6     Morgan Freeman          2
7         Tom Cruise          1
8       Hugh Jackman          1
```

I make a dict with keys the actos names and values the actor name of Nan string

```
actors_dict = {}
for item in range(len(actors_df)):
    name = str(actors_df['Name'].iloc[item])
    freq = actors_df['Frequency'].iloc[item]
    if freq>1:
        actors_dict[name] = name
    else:
        actors_dict[name] = 'NaN'
```

The actors_dict is

```
{'Johnny Depp': 'Johnny Depp',
'Keanu Reeves': 'NaN',
'Robert De Niro': 'Robert De Niro',
'Nicolas Cage': 'NaN',
'Brad Pitt': 'NaN',
'Leonardo DiCaprio': 'NaN',
'Morgan Freeman': 'Morgan Freeman',
'Tom Cruise': 'NaN',
'Hugh Jackman': 'NaN'}
```

Lastly, add the keys in a 'Name1' column and the values in a 'Name2' column of a DataFrame,

```
a = list(actors_dict.keys())
b = list(actors_dict.values())

actors = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([(a[i], b[i])], columns=['Name1', 'Name2']) for i in range(len(a))],ignore_index=True)
```

The output should be,

```
          Name1               Name2
0   Johnny Depp         Johnny Depp
1   Keanu Reeves                NaN
2   Robert De Niro   Robert De Niro
3   Nicolas Cage                NaN
4   Brad Pitt                   NaN
5   Leonardo DiCaprio           NaN
6   Morgan Freeman   Morgan Freeman
7   Tom Cruise                  NaN
8   Hugh Jackman                NaN
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: The solution looks perfect for one column, I wish to use this at scale with multiple name columns and this method shall jumble the order against their respective columns if am right.